# Playwright: How to loop scroll down or show more or page down in a lazy loading page

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, ui-automation, playwright

I am trying to perform a controlled scroll on the home feed of a lazy loading website (similar to LinkedIn.com). But playwright does not support auto-scroll. So I have used the following methods:

1. Find the "Show more results" button and click it

```
await page.locator('button:has-text("Show more results")').click();
```

The issue in this method is that the click goes on an endless loop and times out after default 30 seconds. If I set `timeout:0` then it doesn't time out, it goes on for an infinite loop.

2. While trying to control the click with `waitForSelectoras` shown below:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
     let loadMore = await page.waitForSelector(('button:has-text("Show more results")');
     await loadMore.click({delay: 1000, timeout: 0});
}
```

It throws `Element is not attached to DOM` error. Log as below:

```
elementHandle.click: Element is not attached to the DOM
=========================== logs ===========================
attempting click action
  waiting for element to be visible, enabled and stable
  element is visible, enabled and stable
  scrolling into view if needed
  done scrolling
  performing click action
  <html lang="en" class="theme theme--mercado artdeco os…>…</html> intercepts pointer events
retrying click action, attempt #1
  waiting for element to be visible, enabled and stable
============================================================
```

The only possible way which could see working is:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    await page.keyboard.down('PageDown');
}
```

Any suggestions on better controlled scroll with Playwright library would be helpful :) Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use
`await page.keyboard.press('End');`
to scroll to the end of the page and then try it again with your locator on the show more results button.

Alternately you could also try:

`await page.locator(('button:has-text("Show more results")').scrollIntoViewIfNeeded();`

or more directly
`await page.locator('button:has-text("Show more results")').click()`

because playwright click should automatically scroll the elements into view before trying to click.